# Is the entire static library added to the executable using it, or just the used parts?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

I'm not sure how to search for this question, that's why I asked it.

When you have a project that contains, say 3 classes.

```
Class A
{
   int doSomething();
}

// Depends on A.
Class B
{
 A objA; 
}

// Depends on nothing
Class C
{
   void Terminate();
}
```

And you create a static library containing these 3 classes. When you link in your .lib file with your executable, will 1)  2)

1. **All** the classes in that library be joining the executable (A, B, C)
2. Or just the classes **used** (and it's dependencies)? (A, B, not C)

```
void main()
{
 B b;
 b.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static linking will record from which library and at which file locations the needed classes/functions are. No code other than the mapped location offsets are in the main(). 

Usually, this will look something like:

```
main(){
  compiled_library.dll 0x01234ABC <- offset in file
}
```